# PHP PDO not executing SQL command

Tags: php, pdo

I'm working on a PHP script to reset a user's password. I have an email and a token check setup so that those two must be valid before the user is allowed to reset. So far, everything works up to the point where I insert the password into the database. Here's the code for my PDO (I broke the SQL query at those parts so it's easier to glance over):

```
try {
    $sql = "UPDATE users 
            SET password=:password, sessionTime=:sessionTime, sessionID=:sessionID 
            WHERE sessionID=:sessionID";
    $update = $con->prepare($sql);
    $update->bindValue("password", hash("sha256", $password . $salt), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $update->bindValue("sessionID", "0", PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $update->bindValue("sessionTime", "0", PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $update->execute();
    echo "<br /> Successfully updated the password!";
} catch(PDOException $e) {
     throw new Exception('something went wrong with the password reset', 0, $e);  
}
```

`$salt` and `$password` are defined prior to this, and when I run the script, it outputs `Successfully updated the password!`, however, nothing changes in my database. When I copy and paste the query into phpMyAdmin and change the `:name` parameters to actual strings, it works perfectly (updating my database) and doesn't return any errors - also, I'm not getting anything in `php_error.log`, so I'm not really sure why this isn't working.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you run the script with errorInfo like below and report the results:

```
<?php

try {
    $sql = "UPDATE users 
            SET password=:password, sessionTime=:sessionTime, sessionID=:sessionID 
            WHERE sessionID=:sessionID";
    $update = $con->prepare($sql);
    $update->bindValue("password", hash("sha256", $password . $salt), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $update->bindValue("sessionID", "0", PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $update->bindValue("sessionTime", "0", PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $update->execute();

    var_dump($update->errorInfo());
    echo "<br /> Successfully updated the password!";
} catch(PDOException $e) {
     throw new Exception('something went wrong with the password reset', 0, $e);  
}
```

Comment: Yup, this is what I got back: `array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "00000" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL } `, along with it saying it worked.

Comment: What happens if you echo hash("sha256", $password . $salt); what do you get? also I see you are setting 'sessionID' where sessionID = '0'. So you have two placeholders for :sessionID but only bind it once.

Comment: The hash returns what it should - I was doing that before for error checking. But the `sessionID` thing worked! I thought I was defined it earlier, but I forgot you have to bind each time you do this sort of query. It works perfectly now, thank you!